# Share code/configurations/conventions/gems between Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, dry, rails-engines

## THE PROBLEM

First a little bit of context: I am currently working as a freelancer, developping webapps using Ruby on Rails. Because I am working solo, the need to optimize my workflow is pretty important.

That's why I have always had the same question since I begun working with Rails:
**How can I share code/configuration/conventions/tests between my apps?**

More precisely, I want to share:

- common gems that I always use, with their configuration
- common integration tests, to ensure some conventions
- common view helpers, test helpers, extensions to the core classes, javascript/sass partials
- common files: .gitignore, git hooks, .eslintrc, configuration files of my CI etc

Some concrete examples of what I need in all my apps:

- disable turbolinks by default, to add it later if need be
- use javascript instead of coffeescript
- use slim instead of ERB
- install/configure capistrano
- install a CSS framework (bootstrap, bourbon + neat + refills)

So far I don't really have the need to share models nor controllers.
I don't want to share behavior or functional components of the system itself, I am not looking for a micro-services architecture.

I have found that so far when creating new applications, all this setup work does take me a lot of time. Also, I would like to apply it retro-actively to existing apps when I add something new.

I have done quite a bit of research, but I haven't found a lot of answers. Many people are trying to share models, but few people seem to want to share a common ground between all their apps. Finding the right keywords may have been the problem though.

It seems to me that Rails is really good at DRY within an application, not so easy when trying to DRY between applications.

## POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS

### 1 - Rails application template

The solution I am using right now, described in the [Rails Application Templates guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html), using the same API than the Rails generators described in the [Creating and Customizing Rails Generators & Templates guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).

That's the solution used by Thoughtbot, with their popular [suspenders gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders). In the case of Thoughbot though, they have years of experience to draw from, have many employees and their common setup does not change that much.

Pros:

- saves a lot of time when creating a new application
- really nice API

Cons:

- a lot of duplication: all the apps have the same common code, with the problem of this code getting out-of-sync
- not retroactive: useless to add a common feature to already created apps
- heavy maintenance work: my current workflow is to go through the git log of my apps once per month, and for each commit that could be common to all the apps I have, add it to the application template, and add it to the other apps manually

So far this solution is not that bad, because I only have two applications. But once I will have more, I will suffer from more and more overhead.

A better solution would be maybe to create a generator/rake task for every common new feature, to be able to apply it quickly to existing apps, and call it directly in the application template for new apps.
I haven't tried it though, and I am not really sure it will work. For example what if I want to propagate a one-line change in an existing common file in all the apps?

### 2 - Rails Engine

I have tinkered a bit with the Rails Engines to share code.
I have not understood from the [Getting Started with Engines guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) if I should better use a --full engine or a --mountable one for this specific purpose.

Pros:

- once I update the gem version, all the changes are made available to the app
- DRY: all the common code is in a unique place (the gem)

Cons:

- the gems I would like to share are put in the *.gemspec file, which has not as many features as the Gemfile (from what I understand)
- overhead caused by the need to update the version of the gem in all the apps, migrate to the new API of helpers, etc
- no way to share non-rails files (.gitignore, git hooks, .eslintrc)

This solution has too many important shortcomings.

### 3 - Hybrid solution: Rails Application Template + Rails Engine

Maybe the best would actually to use both the above solutions.
In the gem share helpers and tests, in the rails template share the gems, their configuration/files and other files (for git, linters, etc)
It is indeed adding more complexity and overhead...

### 4 - Use git subtrees

Some people use git subtrees to share folders between multiple webapps.

Cons:

- one has to share whole folders, not easy to share everything I would need, in their different target directories in the rails app
- seems a bit "hacky" to me

---

### Conclusion

Is there another solution than the ones I mentionned above?
What do you think would be the best way to do it?

Comment: You can break up your shared code into a services. Then access service API from the applications. Read up on microservices

Comment: Actually, I am going to edit my post to remove the ambiguity it may have. I am not trying to share behavior, in which case services may help me.
I am trying to share common rails project structure, conventions, helper files (linting, configuration, CI), etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about having a blank "Master" rails app in the git somewhere. With all the settings and configurations you'd like to share. When creating a new app from scratch, you can merge the "Master" into it to apply the defaults. When you have an existing app, same thing, just merge and resolve conflicts as needed.This also gives you the ability to override the merged code if needed to.

Few things I can see wrong with this approach though:

- Rails application name could cause a lot of headaches
- Any updates could cause merge conflicts

Comment: This is an idea that I had never found when researching the topic. It seems nice as a way to apply common code to an existing project at a given time, but as you say, propagating new updates would be harder, because all of the merge conflicts will have to be resolved once more.

Comment: @Sathors Give it a try. Maybe even just extract the files you want to share, too keep the code leaner

Answer (score 1):

I created a tool to deal with this when working in nodejs projects. But the tool is really just a command line tool so you should be able to use it.

https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-builder

It is a concept with creating a dictator that dictates parts of your code base.